# Java ArrayList Class: How to get a method to refer to the class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a school project in java and I am trying, in a method, to refer to the class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumberIndex extends ArrayList<Integer> {
  private int s;
  public NumberIndex (){
    super();
    s = 10; // would be better if it was class.size() 
            //but I don't know how to refer to the class
  }
  public NumberIndex (int x){
    super(x);
    s = x;
  }
  public void addWord(int num) {
    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
      //trying to make it so that for each Integer in ArrayList,
      // if there exists an Integer that has the value num, nothing would
      //happen. Else creates new Integer and adds it to the List
```

So in order for me to finish this code, all I need is a way to reference the class object NumberIndex itself.

Comment: It appears you should be using a `Set<Integer>` which is a collection without duplicates and you would be better off not having an `s` value and it can only bring your grief.

Comment: Google the `static` keyword. You can reference the actual class object with `NumberIndex.class`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey School requires me to do it this way

Comment: @engineer Sorry. It is a mistake on my part.

Comment: @kuhnroyal I need to create an an object so I can't use static. However, I will look into NumberIndex.class Thanks for that tidbit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since add word is a member function use this. that refers to the current NumberIndex  object.

EDIT:

```
public class NumberIndex extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    public NumberIndex() {
        super(10);//setting the size of your NumberIndex object -> list size
    }

    public NumberIndex(int x) {
        super(x);//setting the size of your NumberIndex object -> list size
    }

    public void addWord(int num) {
        if(!this.contains(num)){//if the current NumberIndex object (list) does not contain num
            this.add(num);//to the current NumberIndex object (list) add num
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it be this.NumberIndex